# Freemind doesn't get started in Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit

Tags: 14.04

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10 from 13.04. After completion of the upgrade I installed Freemind, but it didn't get started even though the installation was complete without any error. I hope somebody has an answer to my question.

Running `freemind` from the terminal shows the following message:

```
$ freemind
Checking Java Version...
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/neo/.freemind/auto.properties (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at freemind.main.FreeMindStarter.readUsersPreferences(FreeMindStarter.java:136)
    at freemind.main.FreeMindStarter.main(FreeMindStarter.java:56)
Panic! Error while loading default properties.
```

UPDATE: I have already upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04, but even after reinstalling, Freemind does not work. The above terminal window message is after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

> Ubuntu announced its 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) release almost 9 months
>   ago, on October 17, 2013. This was the second release with our new 9
>   month support cycle and, as such, the support period is now nearing
>   its end and Ubuntu 13.10 will reach end of life on Thursday, July
>   17th. At that time, Ubuntu Security Notices will no longer include
>   information or updated packages for Ubuntu 13.10.
>
> The supported upgrade path from Ubuntu 13.10 is via Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
>   Instructions and caveats for the upgrade may be found at:

[Upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TrustyUpgrades)

> Ubuntu 14.04 LTS continues to be actively supported with security
>   updates and select high-impact bug fixes. Announcements of security
>   updates for Ubuntu releases are sent to the ubuntu-security-announce
>   mailing list, information about which may be found at:

[Ubuntu Security Announcements](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-security-announce)

Or read about [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

<sub>source: http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2014/06/20/ubuntu-13-10-saucy-salamander-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-17-2014/</sub>

Comment: I have already upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS but even after reinstalling, the Freemind does not work. The above terminal window message is after upgrading to 14.04 LTS.

Comment: @Neo see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Freemind

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu version : 15.10

I experienced same issue.
You need to install openjdk-6 and use it instead of openjdk-7 or 8.

```
# sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
```

Add `JAVA_CMD="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/java"` to `/usr/share/freemind/freemind.sh` i.e.

```
.. (omitted)..

220 JAVA_CMD='/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'
221 if [ "${JAVA_TYPE}" = "sun" ]
222 then
223         _debug "Calling: '${JAVA_CMD} -Dfreemind.base.dir=${freedir} -cp ${CLASSPATH} freemind.main.FreeMindStarter  $@'."
224         ( echo "${DEBUG}" | grep -qe "exit" ) && exit 0 # do not start FreeMind                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
225         "${JAVA_CMD}" -Xmx256M -Dfreemind.base.dir="${freedir}" -cp "${CLASSPATH}" freemind.main.FreeMindStarter "$@"
226 else # non-Sun environments don't work currently.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
227         _debug "Calling: '${JAVA_CMD} -Dgnu.java.awt.peer.gtk.Graphics=Graphics2D -Dfreemind.base.dir=${freedir} -cp ${CLASSPATH} freemind.main.FreeMindStarter  $@'."
228         ( echo "${DEBUG}" | grep -qe "exit" ) && exit 0 # do not start FreeMind
229         "${JAVA_CMD}" -Xmx256M -Dgnu.java.awt.peer.gtk.Graphics=Graphics2D -Dfreemind.base.dir="${freedir}" -cp "${CLASSPATH}" freemind.main.FreeMindStarter "$@"
230 fi
```

And then run `freemind`

```
# freemind
```

AFAIK `freemind` needs to be run using openjdk-6